# Get an array of all value of a key

Tags: bash, jq

I am new to bash and jq. I want an array of all value of a key.
i have tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
jobName=$(echo "$jobResult" | jq '. | to_entries[] | .value.name')
```

but it gave a string to me like this string

***"Basement Parking Construction Site 1" "Basement Parking Construction Site 2"***

Input

```
 {
  "1": {
    "_status_code": 202,
    "_status_message": "Accepted",
    "id": 4120489,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "assigned_to_all": false,
    "billable": false,
    "active": true,
    "type": "regular",
    "has_children": false,
    "billable_rate": 0,
    "short_code": "",
    "name": "Basement Parking Construction Site 1",
    "last_modified": "2019-03-12T10:02:54+00:00",
    "created": "2019-03-12T10:02:54+00:00",
    "filtered_customfielditems": "",
    "required_customfields": [],
    "locations": [],
    "project_id": 0
  },
  "2": {
    "_status_code": 202,
    "_status_message": "Accepted",
    "id": 4120491,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "assigned_to_all": false,
    "billable": false,
    "active": true,
    "type": "regular",
    "has_children": false,
    "billable_rate": 0,
    "short_code": "",
    "name": "Basement Parking Construction Site 2",
    "last_modified": "2019-03-12T10:02:54+00:00",
    "created": "I019-03-12T10:02:54+00:00",
    "filtered_customfielditems": "",
    "required_customfields": [],
    "locations": [],
    "project_id": 0
  }
```

I want an array of all the value with key name

result

```
["Basement Parking Construction Site 1","Basement Parking Construction Site 2"]
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: i am able to get a string with name like this "Basement Parking Construction Site 1" "Basement Parking Construction Site 2"

Answer (score 0):

One of many possible solutions:

```
[.[] | .name]
```

If you want to ensure the values in the resultant array are distinct, you could add the `unique` filter.

### Creating a bash array

If your bash has `readarray`, you can read the "name" values into a bash array, a, as follows:

```
readarray a <<< $(jq '.[] | .name' so-to-bash-array.json)
```

If not, simply use a bash loop.

Depending on your requirements, you might want to use the -r command-line option of `jq`.

Comment: but my data is not  as array but as an object with index as key

Comment: thank you it kind of help me but i dont know how to convert this  list string[ "Basement Parking Construction Site 1", "Basement Parking Construction Site 2" ] to an real array in bash     k=$(echo "$jobResult" | jq '[.[] |.name]')

Comment: In future please be more careful when asking a question on SO.  For guidance, see e.g. [mcve].

Comment: And `[.[] | .name]` is equivalent to `map(.name)`, right?